# SQL to consolidate my rows? Tried using MAX, didn't work as intended. Need to grab the latest row, as well as ignore NULLs

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically need to go from this:

```
+----+----------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+
| ID | PlanYear | Plan_Num | JAN  | FEB  | MAR  | APR  | MAY  | JUN | JUL | AUG |
+----+----------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+
|  1 |     2018 |        3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 333 | 333 | 000 |
|  1 |     2018 |        2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 222  | 222  | 222 | 222 | 222 |
|  1 |     2018 |        1 | 111  | 111  | 111  | 111  | 111  | 111 | 111 | 111 |
+----+----------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+
```

to this:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| ID | PlanYear | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL | AUG |
+----+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1 |     2018 | 111 | 111 | 111 | 222 | 222 | 333 | 333 | 000 |
+----+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I've tried

```
MAX(JAN) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, PlanYear ORDER BY Plan_Num DESC) as JAN
```

but no luck. Probably because they all have Plan_Num up to 3 is my guess.

Any guidance would be appreciated. This is on SQL Server. Thanks!

Comment: Is your sample data truly representative? If Plan_Num 3, Jul had 000, what do you want to see as a result? Please edit your sample data and clarify. Also, what data types are these fields? They look like `VARCHAR`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, if Jul had 000 when Plan_Num was 3, then Jul would be 000 on the bottom table. Varchar everything. I'll edit the first post to be more clear.

Comment: @DaleK , I had tried that, no dice. Ended up having all the same values in one row.

Comment: @DaleK Sorry, didn't think that specific detail would affect the solution.

Comment: It does make a difference - Note that @Chris answer is no longer correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, planYear, max(case when jan is null then 0 else jan), ...
from yourTable
group by id, planYear
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution but works

```
SELECT ID, PlanYear, 
 ( SELECT TOP 1 Jan FROM myTable 
   ORDER BY Jan DESC ), 
 ( SELECT TOP 1 Feb FROM myTable
   ORDER BY Feb DESC )... 
WHERE Jan IS NOT NULL
AND Feb IS NOT NULL 
AND ...
GROUP BY ID, PlanYear
```